# What is the query for COLUMN hashing using SHA-256 algorithm in presto?

Tags: presto

COLUMN hashing using SHA-256 algorithm in presto.

I tried and I am getting hashed column output but I need the output in SHA-256 format in Presto.

Comment: What is "SHA-256 format"? Can you please add some data examples and desired output?

Comment: you should pass binary to sha-256 function? try sha256(to_utf8 ('text'))